# Showing Forum Topic Count 0 because, content access module conflict with Advanced Forum

Tags: nodes

In my project I am working with advanced forum. for this I installed module as below.

- advanced forum
- ACL
- content_access
- chain_menu_access

The issue is after adding Forum Topic into forum, the count of topics display zero (0).
Help for resolve this issue.

Comment: Add a question to your post! Then, try to disable the content access modules in reverse order one by one and see at which point the count is correct. Voilà, you found the module which causes the trouble and you can then debug further.

Comment: The "bcoz" actually had me close to reporting this as spam, before I read the title more closely. Might wanna work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find [solution](https://www.drupal.org/node/1739982#comment-9374669) for my [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1739982) and post it on issue list of [Advanced Forum](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum). Also [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1739982#comment-10165268) is created, and [pushed](https://www.drupal.org/node/1739982#comment-10183874) in to future development.